# Spring Boot Controller not mapping random methods

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I have problem with @RestController and Spring Boot application

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/download")
public class CsvExportController {

    private final ZipFileService zipFileService;

    public CsvExportController(ZipFileService zipFileService) {
        this.zipFileService = zipFileService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/export")
    public void getFile(HttpServletResponse response) {
        DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss");
        String currentDateTime = dateFormatter.format(new Date());

        String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
        String headerValue = "attachment; filename=name-" + currentDateTime + ".zip";
        response.setContentType("application/zip");
        response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

        zipFileService.export(response);
    }

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String test() {
       return "Hello";
    }
}
```

I have problem with GET mapping

```
2022-01-13 22:15:48.196  WARN 11944 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET /download/test
2022-01-13 22:15:48.266  WARN 11944 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET /favicon.ico
```

First endpoint @GetMapping("/export") works and second doesn;t works.
In the latter endpoint, no matter what I return. Here I tested "Hello" but it doesn't work anyway. Interestingly, when I change the path for the first "export" to anything else, it also stops working
Any ideas ?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addMapping("/**")
                //.....
    }

    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
        return new ModelMapper();
    }
}
```

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `doesn't wok`? Does it return a `404`?

Comment: yup No mapping for GET and 404

Comment: Are you sure you are running the latest version of your code?

Comment: yes i'm running the latest version because when i change path name of my first EP  @GetMapping("/export") it stops working

Comment: Can you show your config?

Comment: i've updated post. From the configuration, I only have this

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't add a comment. But I think maybe you could provide more details. Because it's available for me. if it's a  `restapi`, the `/favicon.ico` shouldn't be requested.

Comment: Well, I don't know where this favico comes from. I have nothing to do with it. Even before yesterday, the problem did not occur in general. Yesterday I want to update applications and something like that. I don't have any html jsp jstl files or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try setting the response type to json for test endpoint

`@RequestMapping(produces = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])`

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that SpringBoot is probably trying to find a view with the name of `Hello` and you don't have one. Or have your templates misconfigured.

Try adding `@ResponseBody` annotation to your method and it should return the string *as is*:

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public @ResponseBody String test() {
   return "Hello";
}
```

Comment: Does not help. It probably doesn't matter here. In that first EP when I changes the path eq when I change from GetMapping ("export") to GetMapping ("anythinkElse") it stops working

Comment: @Pablo Santa Cruz he has used `@RestController` so spring does not expect any view to be returned.